# Issue with npm install in Jitsi Meet

Tags: node.js, npm-install, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am facing a problem with building jitsi-meet from source n localhost, I have cloned the repository and run `npm i` command but got the following error

```
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for libflacjs@git+ssh://git@github.com/mmig/libflac.js.git#93d37e7f811f01cf7d8b6a603e38bd3c3810907d (sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for libflacjs@git+ssh://git@github.com/mmig/libflac.js.git#93d37e7f811f01cf7d8b6a603e38bd3c3810907d (sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-native@git+ssh://git@github.com/jitsi/react-native.git#891986ec5ecaef65d1c8a7fe472f86cf84fe7551 (sha512-VYzZHHsE6JV0igL/UV6i52yNiiWPkHdJIIQmUvKafLs2Np02vMlV05fYtlP6F/tF+BGn/lwZtDIc3VAIv+CxSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-native@git+ssh://git@github.com/jitsi/react-native.git#891986ec5ecaef65d1c8a7fe472f86cf84fe7551 (sha512-VYzZHHsE6JV0igL/UV6i52yNiiWPkHdJIIQmUvKafLs2Np02vMlV05fYtlP6F/tF+BGn/lwZtDIc3VAIv+CxSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== but got sha512-RFE7w5z12T4fpnpPh+YhRZ5kHfjClVN170xFh6kZ4ghEg1lCXt4HKjbAqhMEnv8inT/g5q+mhRrrlq4TFTVJIg==. (2023065 bytes)
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yash/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T13_38_45_843Z-debug.log
```

Here is the debug log

```
864 timing auditReport:init Completed in 27656ms
865 timing reify:audit Completed in 29075ms
866 warn tarball tarball data for react-native@git+ssh://git@github.com/jitsi/react-native.git#891986ec5ecaef65d1c8a7fe472f86cf84fe7551 (sha512-VYzZHHsE6JV0igL/UV6i52yNiiWPkHdJIIQmUvKafLs2Np02vMlV05fYtlP6F/tF+BGn/lwZtDIc3VAIv+CxSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
867 http fetch GET 200 https://codeload.github.com/jitsi/react-native/tar.gz/891986ec5ecaef65d1c8a7fe472f86cf84fe7551 1068ms (cache revalidated)
868 warn tarball tarball data for react-native@git+ssh://git@github.com/jitsi/react-native.git#891986ec5ecaef65d1c8a7fe472f86cf84fe7551 (sha512-VYzZHHsE6JV0igL/UV6i52yNiiWPkHdJIIQmUvKafLs2Np02vMlV05fYtlP6F/tF+BGn/lwZtDIc3VAIv+CxSA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
869 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 2014ms
870 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 100ms
871 timing command:install Completed in 60172ms
872 verbose stack Error: sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== but got sha512-RFE7w5z12T4fpnpPh+YhRZ5kHfjClVN170xFh6kZ4ghEg1lCXt4HKjbAqhMEnv8inT/g5q+mhRrrlq4TFTVJIg==. (2023065 bytes)
872 verbose stack     at IntegrityStream.[_onEnd] (/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri/index.js:94:19)
872 verbose stack     at IntegrityStream.emit (/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ssri/index.js:67:35)
872 verbose stack     at IntegrityStream.[maybeEmitEnd] (/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass/index.js:365:12)
872 verbose stack     at IntegrityStream.end (/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass/index.js:243:27)
872 verbose stack     at /home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetcher.js:234:58
873 verbose cwd /home/yash/jitsi-meet
874 verbose Linux 5.11.0-38-generic
875 verbose argv "/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node" "/home/yash/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/npm" "i"
876 verbose node v14.18.1
877 verbose npm  v8.1.0
878 error code EINTEGRITY
879 error sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-7cscxyqMkeUa5PpHOqhIkXgyrmPqxCzYobtXnrnwXFkY5+tvRjwsZqQQ52Z9K4AebDzpNaApK+NVn+gK4CwWUw== but got sha512-RFE7w5z12T4fpnpPh+YhRZ5kHfjClVN170xFh6kZ4ghEg1lCXt4HKjbAqhMEnv8inT/g5q+mhRrrlq4TFTVJIg==. (2023065 bytes)
880 verbose exit 1
```

I am using the following version
ubuntu 20.04.3
node v14.18.1
npm v8.1.0

I have also tried npm v7.0.15 and v7.24.2 with npm ci, but got the same error.

Comment: which command did you try for cloning? and you sure your node is working ok? 
it looks like your cloned repo didn't get cloned properly and something wrong happened